# Character sets supported by LOAD DATA INFILE statement of MySQL

Tags: mysql, file-io, load, binaryfiles

Will 'LOAD DATA INFILE' statement of MySQl support binary files?

Comment: as i understand you can do this.

Comment: Please have a look at http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,291699

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it doesn't.. It reads data only from a text file.

Check [this!](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)